# Connection of two Environments of same Power Automate with Azure Devops

Tags: import, azure-devops, export, environment, power-automate

How to connect two environments of one Power Automate platform with Azure Devops to perform import task from azure devops to import solution zip file from one environment of Power Automate to another environment

Comment: Hi there, I'm little confused about your question. Are you looking for a method to import solution from one environment to another using Azure DevOps?

Comment: Yes, I want to import solution from one environment to another using Azure DevOps